# Windows Server 2012 Service to restart application

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I am trying to upgrade a server from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 and I have a service that restarts an application that needs to be updated, which must be always running in order for it to get its job done propperly (summarizing is an application that reads data sent from several sensors and stores it in a database).

The thing is, Microsoft changed the way services work and it won't work properly in the new server.

Is there a way to keep doing it with a service even if it needs to be done within a user session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask at http://serverfault.com/ instead.